# Proof that Cauchy Criterion implies least upper bound theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is this proof fully complete? In our homework it is worth 10 marks but I feel this proof is too short and simple.

The question is: Show that from the Cauchy criterion for R follows the least-upper-bound property.

Here is answer:

Assume “Every Cauchy sequence of real numbers has
a limit in R”.
Let A be a set which is bounded above, and let $x_1$ be an upper
bound. If $x_1 = supA$ we are done. Otherwise let k be the smallest
integer such that $x_1-\frac{1}{k}$ is an upper bound (for A) and set $x_2 = x_1 −\frac{1}{k}$ .
Repeat, defining $x_{n+1} = x_n−k_n^{-1}$ where $k_n$ is the smallest integer such that $x_n −k_n^{-1}$ is an upper bound for A; (if at any stage $x_n = supA$ we are done ). The sequence {xn} is bounded below (by A) so that $∑k_n^{-1} < ∞$

Comment: The cauchy criterion for R states that every cauchy sequence of real numbers converges, is the sequence you have defined cauchy? If so could you elaborate by first proving it is indeed cauchy?

Comment: To be clear, your sequence IS cauchy, but as you've said that your homework was 10 marks, it is worth proving its cauchy. This shouldn't be too difficult, as it amounts to just proving that $k_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers. Once this is shown, you have proved your sequence is cauchy, and then proving that it converges to the least upper bound of A can be done by contradiction.

Comment: It is assumed that it is Cauchy but maybe I should do it anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is a good exercise.